# Is Mutan still used as language?

Tags: contract-development, history

Mutan was designed by Jeffrey Wilcke as a Go-like language for contract development. Is it being used and developed / maintained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Mutan was [deprecated](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/922/mutan-faq) in march 2015 in the favour of Solidity.

Solidity was introduced with the intention to (possibly) replace all three initial high level languages (Mutan, Serpent and LLL) some day.