# What is the best language to start programming in Ethereum?

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development

I have an introduction to C++ under my belt (very simple stuff), and other skills like an occasional R script, that's about it.

Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One eye on solc, which has similar syntax compared to C, Java, or C++, but with ethereum specific add-ons.  Put the other eye on Javascript, mos def.  Maybe put a third eye on html.

Comment: Solc is the compiler for the Solidity language

Answer (score 3):

You should learn **JavaScript** and libraries like m[eteor.js](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumjs-lib), [web3.j](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js)s or ethereumjs-lib to build DApps.

To deploy them on the blockchain, [you should learn](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) **Solidity**, the one contract language [to rule them all](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/368/87). With the best documenation and built to survive the other contract languages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out Vyper @ http://viper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-vyper.html! It's still in experimental phases but it's the "python like" equivalent of solidity. :+)