# how to build a smart contract using c++ in ubuntu

Tags: contract-development

Can someone please assist me in creating a smart contract using cpp in ubuntu. I have installed the required software for ethereum, but all I can find is assistance on building smart contracts using Solidity. Can someone please help me or direct me on how to build a smart contract using c++ coding language.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a compiler that compiles c++ to EVM assembly.

Comment: then can you suggest me on how to work on it? is it possible only with solidity then?

Comment: See [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/368/8755) for a list of languages that can compile to EVM assembly. Solidity is definitely the biggest right now, Viper/Bamboo are new and don't have a ton of tooling support yet.