# Developing a lisp(y) contract language

Tags: contract-design, clients, lll

While it would not be possible to implement everything, could it be useful for domain specific applications to have a lisp based contract language that implements a certain subset of features? Probably couldn't have call/cc or TCO, but It would be nice to in theory write contracts capable of writing other contracts. Why has LLL been abandoned? Looking around I don't see any way of using it with geth. Serpent compiles to LLL supposedly so there should be some kind of interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is LLL still used as language?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/348/is-lll-still-used-as-language)

Comment: Legit question and not certainly a duplicate.

Comment: The question has been edited since my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a contract language with Lisp syntax called LLL. Well at least it was used in the early days and probably is not well maintained. See this topic: [Is LLL still used as language?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/348/is-lll-still-used-as-language)

EDIT: regarding your proposal of *contracts writing other contracts* - it is already possible. In Solidity new contracts can be instantiated and deployed, but those have to be written upfront. No self modifying code and definitely no Lisp-like macros :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like LLL is still alive, I've found this somewhat recent [article](https://media.consensys.net/an-introduction-to-lll-for-ethereum-smart-contract-development-e26e38ea6c23) and this [Youtube series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3xMk-6xwRE) covering LLL.