# Can I write and deploy smart contracts in Java language?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, java

I am a Java developer. I want to write a smart contract using Java and deploy it to a private blockchain network.

Does Ethereum provide the facility to write smart contracts using Java language? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: May you can any help from here : https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj

Comment: Check out tendermint for smart contracts in any language: https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/. Here's an example application in Java: https://github.com/wolfposd/TMChat

Comment: A complete tutorial can be found [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-blockchain-hello-world-smart-contract-with-java-9b6ae2961ad1)

Comment: Check out Aion, they just launched the AVM (Aion virtual machine which runs Java bytecode on the blockchain), which means you can write your smart contract in Java using existing tools and IDEs. Here's a link to their docs: https://docs.aion.network/docs/aion-virtual-machine.(its actually pretty dope)

Answer (score 6):

No, the only currently supported languages for contract development are lll ([dead](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/348/is-lll-still-used-as-language)), [serpent](https://ethereumbuilders.gitbooks.io/guide/content/en/serpent_tutorials.html) and [solidity](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with the later being most used.

Answer (score 6):

Currently, Smart Contracts can be written in three languages:

> Solidity - Similar to JavaScript
>
> Serpent - Python derivative
>
> LLL(Lisp Like Language) - Similar to Assembly

You can find more information about these languages [here](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/contracts.html#ethereum-high-level-languages).

Solidity is designed especially for writing smart contracts and is the flagship language of Ethereum. You can start reading about it [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 6):

To start you can use [web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j). It is Java library that allow the iteration of java application with contracts in the Ethereum network.

It doesn't provide the capability to write contracts in java, but you can interact with contracts written in Solidity.

It generates Smart Contract wrappers in Java from a Solidity compiled binary and ABI file.

Once you've generated the wrapper code with web3j, you will be able to deploy, then call the methods on the above contract example as follows:

[Ex](https://docs.web3j.io/smart_contracts.html#solidity-smart-contract-wrappers):

```
SimpleStorage simpleStorage = SimpleStorage.deploy(
    <web3j>, <credentials>, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT,
    BigInteger.ZERO);  // ether value of contract

TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = simpleStorage.set(
        new Uint256(BigInteger.valueOf(1000))),
        .get();

Uint256 result = simpleStorage.get()
        .get();
```

Comment: Please don't submit link-only answers. Describe the content and how it solves the problem.

Comment: I think is misleading. You can write your code in a few languages for which an EVM compiler exists, but Java isn't one of them. JavaScript != Java. You can indeed deploy bytecode via JavaScript using Web3 but it seems like we are far away from the original question.

Comment: @RobHitchens: plesase note this is web3j, not web3 - it is, as described a Java library.

Comment: (whoever downvoted this, the answer seems to have improved since)

Answer (score 5):

The ICON blockchain will support java smart contracts in [ICON 2.0](https://github.com/icon-project/goloop) due to be released August 2021 and currently running on a [testnet](https://medium.com/helloiconworld/icon-2-0-alpha-version-released-89c8063ab1a1).

You can also checkout code examples -> https://github.com/icon-project/java-score-examples.

Answer (score 4):

You can not write contracts in Java, but deploying should work with the [Ethereum Contract API](https://github.com/adridadou/eth-contract-api) native in Java. The goal is to ease the integration of Ethereum in a Java project.

> - Easy configuration of the network and keypair use
> - Create an interface for a smart contract
> - Have type safety in regards of input and output values
> - Easy transaction creation
> - Easy synchronization when creating a transaction
> - Transaction creation returns Future, simple calls returns the value itself

On [youtube is a short presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWeNSvori4I&index=1&list=PLaM7G4Llrb7wPiT2G75tj2JQr8qg6P5hi) (15 minutes) from the Berlin Ethereum meetup.

Answer (score 4):

It's not out yet but you might be interested in Corda, which is being developed by Mike Hearn and his team on behalf of the R3 consortium.  This targets Java developers, and doesn't use a blockchain, as is appropriate for a lot of private blockchain projects in the financial sector.

Per this discussion some code will be released soon:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3YTSwB5UrEI

Comment: "doesn't use a blockchain, as is appropriate for a lot of private blockchain projects" Upvoted for this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Jthereum supports writing contracts for the Ethereum blockchain in Java.

It is a commercial product targeted at enterprise use.

https://Jthereum.com

The product is currently in beta testing, but is available for download and use at no charge at this time (4/19/2021)

Comment: Nice to know, please correct URL to be like `<http://jthereum.com>` so it is clickable:
http://jthereum.com