# Java Client for Ethereum Contract

Tags: testrpc, java

I am trying to create an Ethereum Contract, through my java application, has anyone done this before? how do you pass the JASONRPC command via java method
I am using TESTRPC

Comment: please check https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7459/can-i-write-and-deploy-smart-contracts-in-java-language

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have worked with Java and Ethereum before.
I suggest using Web3J: https://github.com/web3j/web3j Just read the whole documenation and start by implementing the Client-Version-example yourself. If you have any questions regarding web3j, you can either post here or open a ticket on Github.

Comment: I downloaded the Web3j from the Git repository. How do I link it to my eclipse project so I can then install it? I don't really understand the instructions in the documentation about Maven and Gradle.

Comment: *"import it", not install it